# How optimize hidesBackButton code for animation in segue?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uiviewanimation

I'm making segue from `DynamicVC` to `SearchVC` programmatically:

```
@objc func goToSearchVC() {

        let searcVC = SearchVC()

        //Hide system navigation controller back button
        searcVC.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        searcVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "closeBtn_20"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(closeBtnTapped))
        searcVC.navigationItem.title = ""

        navigationController?.pushViewController(searcVC, animated: true)
        searcVC.view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    }
```

`hidesBackButton` executes very slowly, "Back" button flashing in the segue animation:

[image: hidesBackButton executes very slowly]

How can i fix this? Is it possible to optimize this? Thanks.

Comment: Try `navigationController?.pushViewController(searcVC, animated: false)`. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: No. I want to keep animation. It's not the solution.

Comment: I would suggest configuring the navigation bar in `viewDidLoad` function for SearchVC. If you don't want to do that, try initializing searchVC with customizations in `viewWillDisappear(_:)` instead of `goToSearchVC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with flashing "Back" button using this code:

```
let transition:CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype =  kCATransitionFromRight
    self.navigationController!.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(searchVC, animated: false)
```

another types of transition for use:

```
kCATransitionFromLeft

kCATransitionFromBottom

kCATransitionFromRight

kCATransitionFromTop
```